# PyQt: keyPressEvent and keyReleaseEvent - holding press without debounce

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside

I want implement a `QDialog`, in which a key is pressed for some time (seconds) and is released afterwards.

I tried doing this with `keyPressEvent` and `keyReleaseEvent` functions.

The problem I get is that when a key is pressed the debounce (`keyReleaseEvent`) occurs very quickly, which is not desired in my case.

Here, is what I do:

```
def keyPressEvent(self, eventQKeyEvent):
    key = eventQKeyEvent.key()
    if key == 54:
    print('pressed')  # 6


def keyReleaseEvent(self, eventQKeyEvent):
    key = eventQKeyEvent.key()
    if key == 54:
    print('released')  # 6
```

Output:

```
'pressed'
'released'
'pressed'
'released'
'pressed'
'released'
...
'pressed'
'released'
```

I would like to get either:

```
'pressed'
'released'
```

or:

```
'pressed'
'pressed'
'pressed'
...
'pressed'
'pressed'
'released'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [isAutoRepeat](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qkeyevent.html#isAutoRepeat):

```
def keyReleaseEvent(self, eventQKeyEvent):
    key = eventQKeyEvent.key()
    if key == 54 and not eventQKeyEvent.isAutoRepeat():
        print('released')
```